# Responsive div with same width and height and on small media screen move to new line

Tags: html, css

I am trying to achieve a responsive div which contains a image whereas the multiple div should be of same size when they are in a bigger size screen and on smaller screen the width should be auto adjusted and they should one on new line 
, My problem is the second div width is not same as the first one that is stretched on bigger screens.
[**Js Fiddel**](http://jsfiddle.net/cUCvY/2284/#&togetherjs=oRtkhoD89S)
Example:
[image]
Css:

```
.wrapper { 
  border : 2px dotted #ccc; padding: 2px; 
}

.wrapper div {
   width: 100%; 
   min-height: 200px;
   padding: 10px;
   -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
   -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
   box-sizing: border-box;
}
#one { background-color: gray; }
#two { background-color: blue; }

@media screen and (min-width: 600px) {
   .wrapper {
      height: auto; overflow: hidden; // clearing 
   }
   #one { width: 200px; float: left; }
   #two { margin-left: 200px; }
}
```

Html:

```
 <div class="wrapper">
    <div id="one">one</div>
    <div id="two">two</div>

  </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

update this css

```css
.wrapper { 
  border : 2px dotted #ccc; padding: 2px; 
}

.wrapper div {
   width: 100%; 
   min-height: 200px;
   padding: 10px;
   -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
   -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
   box-sizing: border-box;
}
#one { 
    background-color: gray;
}
#two { 
    background-color: blue;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 600px) {
   .wrapper {
      height: auto; overflow: hidden; // clearing 
   }
   #one { width: 50%; float: left; }
   #two { margin-left: 200px; }
}
```

Need to set `width: 50%` on `#one` div

Comment: but on big screen the image are breaking up see the result hear http://jsfiddle.net/cUCvY/2284/#run

Comment: breaking up meant image will go outside of DIV or ?

Comment: the second image just goes down and gets bigger

Comment: the problem is that you are using `margin-left`

Comment: if making  `#one { width: 50%; float: left; }` it works fine

Comment: if image will flow you can set max-width: 100% on img or overflow: hidden on parent div